# Restore sentence segmentation

Tags: nlp

I have list of consequent 5-gram words from one text like this:

> utilize use a growth delay
>
> induce change in tumor physiological
>
> change in tumor physiological parameter
>
> TBF use laser Doppler flowmetry
>
> tifp use a win method
>
> polarographic microelectrode method be apply
>
> confirm ONC as a radiation
>
> ONC as a radiation sensitizer

...

Some of them like *induce change in tumor physiological* and *change in tumor physiological parameter* can be glued. But for the majority of 5 grams text between them is missed. What is the possible approach/algorithm to restore initial text's sentence segmentation?

Comment: I'd suggest adding some example inputs and their expected outputs to help define exactly what you are trying to achieve.